# Not able to create ingress resource in kubernetes with service in different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to create an ingress resource as below, my issue is my service1 and service2 are  located in a different namespace in kubernetes. so in order my ingress resource to connect both the services I am providing as `service2.<namespace>`. but I am not able to create as (.) is not allowed. How can I point my service.2 present in a different namespace?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: "/"
          backend:
            serviceName: service1
            servicePort: 1000
        - path: "/test"
          backend:
            serviceName: service2.test
            servicePort: 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in two ways:

- You can create another `Ingress` resource in `test` namespace for the `/test` path.
- If you are not running on GKE, you can also create a `Service` of type `ExternalName` in current namespace which maps to `service2` service in `test` namespace. Then you can use the name `service2` to refer to `service2.test`

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service2
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: service2.test.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 2000
```